# Voix passive de profiter

Tags: sens, prépositions, passif

Selon wiktionary (https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/profiter), le verbe « profiter » peut être écrit avec deux prépositions. Quand on l'utilise avec « à »:

> Alice profite à Bob.

Cela veut dire qu'Alice fait quelque chose qui est rentable pour Bob.

Mais quand on utilise la préposition « de »:

> Alice profite de Bob.

Cela veut dire qu'Alice fait quelque chose qui est rentable pour elle-même mais c'est un peu comme si elle utilisait Bob pour réussir.

Quel sens a cette phrase qui est formé avec la voix passive?

> Bob est profité par Alice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***« Alice profite à Bob »*** peut être reformulé comme suit :

- Alice est profitable pour Bob.
- Bob prend avantage *<sub>(des forces ou des faiblesses)</sub>* d’Alice.
- Bob tire profit d’Alice.

***« Alice profite de Bob »*** au passif peut devenir :

- Bob fait profiter de lui par Alice.

***« Bob est profité par Alice »*** ou ***« Bob est profité d’Alice »*** sont très inhabituels. Je n’ai jamais entendu ce genre d’affirmation de la part de francophones de naissance.

Comment: Yes, *est profité par/de* is never used in French.